# ColdFusion Site Transfer

Tags: web-services, coldfusion, hosting

I had an agency run my site for awhile and no longer using their service. They gave me a drop box link with my site in it. I never used coldfusion so im am super super lost. I signed up with hostek.com, and there are zero help. How do I get my coldfusion site back up and running. I thought it would be a simple drag and drop, and sadly I am getting errors. Any type of help would be greatful, and tipping nicely if I need a one on one.

Comment: Was there a database component to your site and if so, did you get a backup of that as well? If there's a database, you'll also have to configure a datasource in the ColdFusion Admin. Can you update with a sample of the type of error you're getting?

Comment: Depending on how the app was architected, you may have to change settings in a .cfm or .cfc file as well. If you are not a CF/Web developer, you might want to hire one for an hour or two to get your app back up and running.

Comment: @iKnowKungFoo the site is located @ http://friendthem-com.securec44.ezhostingserver.com/

Comment: @BenKoshy are you a cf/web developer that could do this for me? The other developer is being very difficult and I am not sure my way around coldfusion

Comment: The error that your site is currently throwing references a missing include file.  Did you keep the exact same directory structure under your new site (and extract all of the files to it)?

Comment: I would have to agree that you may want to higher a developer, it shouldnt cost you too much to move it over for you.  Some things you may need to setup include databases and datasources, scheduled tasks (if applicable), security/permissions, adjust file paths, etc...  For example, if you have a SQL DB, that is going to need to be added to your server and you are going to need to setup a new username and password from hostek for it.  Then update your code, which may contain a global variable, or may need to be updated on multiple pages.

Comment: That error could mean that you need a URL rewrite rule too. Not sure how you direct contact people on StackOverflow but you can email me at 'cf *AT* animex.com' and can see if I can help you out.

Comment: The old developer didn't send my the correct files. Some how I was able to gain access to the old server and copied to the full dir and uploaded it again and everything works perfect!

Comment: "some how"? :D  Glad you got it going!

Comment: well now it seems like I need to add the database and point it to it. I have the backup now Just got to figure out how this works. Where would I look to make sure it pointing the right way? @BenKoshy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checklist of things to do when moving a site:

- Get the database files. If it is SQL Server, there will be at least one main DB file and one  log file. You may want to consider doing the DB move as a separate operation from the site move.
- Get all the files in the directory where the site exists. Depending on the Web Server it may be a virtual directory.
- Get database connection information. This exists in the CF Admin.

This will get most sites up and running, but you may also have to...

- Copy over missing CF_ custom tags;
- Copy over DLLs for missing CFX_ custom tags;
- Setup path mappings in CF Admin.
- Setup up scheduled tasks

If you are moving to a new server, make sure it has all the ColdFusion patches and all the Java Runtime patches.

There are many many more things on the maybe list. You would have to provide the error message to get more details.

Comment: Don't forget the actual database.